# Get all docs which not contains the key?

Tags: elasticsearch

For example,i have 2 type docs,such as

```
{
    "field2":"xx",
    "field1","x"
}
{
    "field1","x"
}
```

The one has 2 fields(`field1` and `field2`),another one just has 1 field(`field1`).

Now,i want to query all docs which do not have `field2` field?

**EIDT**
dsl:

```
 {
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "exists": {
                        "field": "LableToMember"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

doc:

```
{
    "LableToMember": [
        {
            "xxx": "xxx",
            "id": "1"
        }
    ],
    "field2":"xxx"
}
```

`LableToMember` is a nested field.I find `exists` api can't be used for nested field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that in ES 5.x the [`missing` query has been removed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html#_literal_missing_literal_query) in favor of the `exists`  one.

So if you want to be forward compatible, you should prefer using this:

```
POST /_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": {
                "exists": {
                    "field": "field2"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to retrieve all docs which don't have `field2` or have `field2` with a given value, you can do it like this:

```
POST /_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": {
              "exists": {
                "field": "field2"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "field2": "somevalue"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How i to get the docs which not contains `field2` or `field2` equal to `xxx`?

Comment: I find `exists` api can't be used for nested field? I updated the question.

Comment: Of course you can, you just need to nest the exists query within a `nested` query.

Answer (score 0):

In short you want to query those documents which have `field2` missing. You can use [Missing Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-missing-query.html) like:

```
"filter" : {
              "missing" : { "field" : "field2" }
           }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Did you see the _Deprecated in 2.2.0._?